# Unit Testing with groovy

Tags: groovy, junit4

New to groovy and java.  Installed groovy,plugin with eclipse and created a groovy project
I am able to run groovy scripts  and groovy class.  But GroovyTestCase class is not getting resolved. Any help is appreciated.

```
package p1
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase

class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase { //GroovyTestCase keyword is showing this error: type junit.framework.TestCase cannot be resolved.  It is indirectly referred from required .class files

    void testSomething() {
        assert 1 == 1
        assert 2 + 2 == 4 : "We're in trouble, arithmetic is broken"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

GroovyTestCase is JUnit 3, If you want to use Junit4, don't extend the class, instead use the @Test annotations like in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnit as it was pointed out before, but on Groovy usually the library that it is used it is called [Spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/). Next question would be Why Spock, then check [this out](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/WhySpock).

We have been using it for a while, and it works like a charm. Highly recommended.